# Error received while trying to print class variables

Tags: java

```
package mydate;

public class MyDate {

  private int day=1;
  private int month=1;
  private int year=2000;

public MyDate(int day,int month,int year)
{
  this.day=day;
  this.month=month;
  this.year=year;
  System.out.println(day+"  "+month+"  "+year);
}  
 System.out.println(day+"  "+month+"  "+year);// I am getting an error on this line saying cannot find symbol.How to print class variables of MyDate?

}
```

---

```
package mydate;

public class TestMyDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 MyDate today=new MyDate(22,7,1964); 
}
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Ask a question. Say what you expect to happen, what's happening instead, and why that surprises you. Describe *why* you think you should be getting a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `System.out.println(day+"  "+month+"  "+year);// I am getting an error on this line saying cannot find symbol. How to print class variables of MyDate?` must be in a method of the class or the constructor. You cant just stick it anywhere in the class definition. I would put it in a method rather than a constructor anyway like the following:

For example:

```
 public void printDate() {
     System.out.println(day+"  "+month+"  "+year);// I am getting an error on this line saying cannot find symbol. How to print class variables of MyDate? 
 }
```

Then, in your main() you can call that method on your object reference:

```
 MyDate today=new MyDate(22,7,1964);  
 today.printDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in a class you cannot have a print statement. Only in functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have free-floating statements in a class. Try something like:

```
public void printInfo() {
    System.out.println(day+"  "+month+"  "+year);
}
```

Then you could do

```
MyDate today=new MyDate(22,7,1964);
today.printInfo();
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.i am new to java hence this query.Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove System.out.println from Class.It will work fine.